# Moving Web service from Http to Https

Tags: .net, web-services

i have a web service and want to publish it as https.With current settings,i can publish it in http but i dont know what to do for https.What must i do in server?I searched something internet but couldnt find usefull and basic informations about it.I use Visual studio 2008.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First  of all you need to enable SSL Support in your Websever, Assuming you are using IIS 7 you can follow [this guide from iis.net](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/144/how-to-setup-ssl-on-iis-70/). Then you should head over to [this blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2003/12/04/41154.aspx) and read a little about Trusted Certificates when handleing Webservices.

However, when setting up the webserver to support SSL, it should not be any difference in how you deploy it, as far as I know you just tell the webserver to respond to HTTPS instead of HTTP.

[This article: "HOW TO: Secure XML Web Services with Secure Socket Layer in Windows 2000"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307267) from Microsoft might also be helpfull, however it assumes you are using Windows 2000 and probably a earlier version of .NET and IIS 6. But check it out, these combined will give you a good overview of how to set up your enviornment.